# Image Hide in and hide out using event handler

Tags: javascript, event-handling, cross-browser, dom-events

I am working on a web page which contains a list of items and sub items for display. In the Div element, I am setting up the values, image. Using the image show and hide option On click event handler is triggered. This seems to be working fine with IE9, but doesn't work with other browsers (FireFox, Chrome and safari).

```
<div id="Type_A Medicine" value="H" entity="Type A Medicine" onClick="showHide(this,'MIE_Type_A Medicine')"><img src='<%=request.getContextPath()%>/images/plus.gif'>Type A Medicine</div>

function showHide(ctrl,id)
{
    if (ctrl.value == "H")
    {
            ctrl.value = "S";
            ctrl.innerHTML = "<img src='<%=request.getContextPath()%>/images/minus.gif'>" +ctrl.getAttribute("entity");
            showBlock(id);
    }
    else if (ctrl.value == "S")
    {
        ctrl.value = "H";
        ctrl.innerHTML = "<img src='<%=request.getContextPath()%>/images/plus.gif'>" + ctrl.getAttribute("entity");
        hideBlock(id);
    }
}


function hideBlock(blockId)
{
    var str = "document.all." + blockId + ".style.display='none'";
    eval(str);
}

function showBlock(blockId)
{
    var str = "document.all." + blockId + ".style.display=''";
    eval(str);
}
```

I still couldn't figure out the difference with the list of browsers. Kindly help...

Comment: You al;so can't have spaces in your id values.

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing it is because you use an invalid ID syntax. ID's cannot have spaces. If you use invalid HTML you can't expect javascript to work the same way across browsers.

```
id="Type_A Medicine"
```

Also, you never post the code for showBlock or hideBlock where you pass the ID in. Can't tell what goes wrong there without code.

Comment: I am sure that is the problem

Comment: Thanks for the reply.Sorry it was a typo error.But it doesn't have any impact on the click event even after the change..

Answer (score 1):

To retrieve non-standard attributes, you should use `.getAttribute()` rather than trying to access them as properties.

So `ctrl.entity` should be `ctrl.getAttribute("entity")` and the same for other non-standard attributes.  Run this example in Chrome: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/Lxna7/.

Also, you should remove the space from your ID value as that's not a legal character and makes the id unusable in many circumstances (where a space is a delimiter between identifiers).

Answer (score 0):

Try closing correctly the image tags to see if that fix the problem:

```
<img src="path/file.html" />
```

Comment: Thanks to everyone for their replies and support.I have worked out the changes and found that only the hide out feature works fine in all the browsers and doesn't work well. But still facing problems with hide in feature.